# Android studio not showing red underlines in project structure

Tags: android, underline

Eclipse used to show RED UNDERLINES wherever there was some error in project view. One could easily see all the errors without checking  each file individually for errors. Is there any way to do the same in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

## ***For Android Studio***

**File > Power Save Mode** check if it is checked or not.

**if it is checked it will not show the red line for error**

## ***For Eclipse***

[image]You can see the list of problems from

**Window → Show View → Problems**

**OR** you can search using **QuickAccess** option.

Comment: @deniz is there any other option behind Power Save Mode that highlights the errors in editor ?  my android studio not showing the errors, I need debug  the code manually .

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly I didn't get any red lines in Android Studio. Invalidating caches didn't work (Files > Invalidates Caches...).

What worked was to quit Android Studio, delete the `.idea`-folder and reopen Android Studio.